Sitecore CMS Search not working
I have recently upgraded Sitecore 8.2 to 9.2
The Sitecore CMS (content tree) search does not return any values. It's using Lucene search. I performed a re-index but had no luck. What index does it use internally?
I have not yet configured XConnect but I don't think that could be the reason why it's not working.
Please anyone can help? I tried everything I could. Thanks.


Are there any exceptions in log files?

Is this standalone or scaled? Lucent is not supported in scaled and is depreciated in later versions. Perhaps a good time to switch to solr? https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/using-solr,-lucene,-or-azure-search.html

Two things

It uses sitecore_master_index, By default if you just re-index it should start searching the data but in your case it is not happening

Can you check the logs and see if you are getting exception like below?
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
Source: mscorlib
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name)



Or any other exceptions?

Can you check showconfig.aspx and double check the <index id="sitecore_master_index" and its configuration? I hope there is not excluded path or crawler path etc are proper?

Let's check all of these and come back

Sitecore supports three different search engines: Solr, Azure Search, and Lucene. You must consider several factors, such as the purpose of the specific environment, your scaling requirements, and the hosting environment, when you choose a search engine.
Solr is the default search engine for content search and xConnect search for on-premise installations
Use Lucene only for a development or single server evaluation environment that runs Sitecore Experience Manager. You cannot use Lucene in a scaled environment. You can only use Lucene for content search. xConnect does not support Lucene. We do not recommend or support Lucene in a production environment.
Refer to the Sitecor document for more details.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/using-solr,-lucene,-or-azure-search.html
It's recommended to use Solr as Support for the Lucene search engine is no longer included in Sitecore 9.3, and later
Hope this helps.
